# A column as primary key or two foreign keys as primary key

Tags: database-design

I have the following database design:

[image]

An `E-Report` has one `QAP` which has some `Requirement`s. A `QAP` and its `Requirement`s can be used in more than one `E-Report`.

Every `Requirement` will have a Yes/No confirmation in each E-Report. I've added `EReportReq` to store requirements confirmations values (users will set these values).

And also, each `Requirement` will have more than one `Image` on each `E-Report`. `EReportReqImg` will store `Image` and `Requirement` relationship.

If you need more details about this database model, please tell me.

My question is about `EReportReq` table. I'm not sure if I need a column as primary key (`EReportReqId`) or I can use `eReportId` and `requirementId` as primary key.

If I use these two columns, `eReportId` and `requirementId` as primary key, I will need to add these two to `EReportReqImg` table, so I don't know if this approach is better than mine.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is about `EReportReq` table. I'm not sure if I need a column as primary key (`EReportReqId`) or I can use `eReportId` and `requirementId` as primary key.

You can use either of them - none of them is absolutely "better". Just be careful that if you decide to use the first approach, also create a UNIQUE constraint on `{eReportId, requirementId}`.

The fist approach (with non-identifying relationship and surrogate key) leads to:

- "leaner" foreign keys in child tables (which is `EReportReqImg` in this case) - as you already noted,
- the cascading ON UPDATE doesn't propagate to children (so if you update `EReport.eReportId`, only `EReportReq.eReportId` is cascade-updated, but not `EReportReqImg.eReportId`)
- and can be more friendly to ORMs.

On the other hand, the second approach (with identifying relationship and natural keys):

- has potentially less need for JOINs (e.g. you don't need to `EReportReqImg JOIN EReportReq` just to find-out `requirementId` - you have it directly in `EReportReqImg.requirementId`),
- is better suited for [clustered tables](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) (e.g. `EReportReq` rows with the same `eReportId` will be stored physically "close", which may significantly benefit some queries)
- avoids additional index on the surrogate key.

Since you have a small number of child tables, "fat" FKs don't matter much and since we are dealing with IDs, they are unlikely to change and cascading ON UPDATE is unlikely to be a problem. So, my instinct is to go with the second approach, but you might have some other considerations that might tip your decision in a different direction...

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from this state:

> I will need to add these two to EReportReqImg

In general usage of 2 FK as PK is normal practice for non-changeable data. So if `EReportReq` is not supposed to be changed in manner that you will drag it to another `requirementId` or `eReportId` then use compound key. Otherwise it is more robust and efficient to use single-value primary key - because it is not changed during the time and as result you don't need write trigger or use tricky cascade to update children tables.

Other option to review is simplicity of result SQL, *simple better than complex* - write `INNER JOIN` with 2 fields is complex construction and there is potentially bug-place for miss one of the keys.