# Draw Many to Many Relationship in ERD

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

[image]

Many to many relationships should have a solid line, strong relationship.
In the given diagram, ther right side sample is surely incorrect, the relationship
line show be solid. However, **what is the appropaite relationship for the left side diagram, should it be dashed (weak relationship) or solid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many to many relationships should have a solid line, strong relationship.

What notation are you using? Looks like a variant of IE (Information Engineering).

At any rate, I guess this depends on the notation/conventions being used and in this particular case the logical model seems consistent with the physical one, except for the requirement that a Project must be connected to at least one Employee, which cannot be easily<sup>1</sup> mapped to the physical database.

> In the given diagram, ther right side sample is surely incorrect, the relationship line show be solid.

Not necessarily. There is nothing preventing you from migrating the parent PKs into an **alternate** key in the junction table and using a surrogate PK. This would make the relationships "non-identifying", warranting the usage of dashed lines.

---

<sup>1</sup> It would require [circular deferred FKs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12387403/533120).

Comment: I'm using Crow's Foot Noration. "There is nothing preventing you from migrating the parent PKs into an alternate key in the junction table and using a surrogate PK." Right, but i'm assuming the junction table has a fully borrowed PK without the intention of changing it to an alternate key in the future.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.drawerd.com/relationship/many-many

With [DrawERD](https://drawerd.com): simple web ui can do it.
[image]