# SQL Server + Composite key or Unique Id

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am fairly new to database design, for many to many relationship, what is the differences and implications of creating a composite key and a unique id for e.g.

`Country` table

```
CountryID
CountryName
```

`Language` table

```
LanguageID
LangugageName
```

Many to Many table - using composite:

```
CountryID  Pkey
LanguageID Pkey
```

OR

Using unique Id:

```
AutoID Pkey
CountryID 
LanguageID
```

Comment: check the updated answer that will give you clear idea ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Composite Key :**

A composite key is a combination of more than one column to identify a unique row in a table.
composite key can be a primary key .

**PRIMARY KEY**

The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.

so its all depend on your requirement

in **first design**

```
Many to Many Table:
Using composite:
CountryID  Pkey
LanguageID Pkey
```

if you use this desing than CountryID  and LanguageID  is composite primary key.i.e here

data of the table will be

```
CountryId  LaguageID
  1           1 //valid
  1           2 //valid
  1           3 //valid
  1           1//not valid data as its form composite primary key
```

and in **second design**

```
Using Unique Id:
AutoID Pkey
CountryID 
LanguageID
```

AutoID  is become primary key so this will allow data lke thsi

```
AutoId    CountryId  LaguageID
 1          1           1 //valid
 2          1           2 //valid
 3          1           3 //valid
 4          1           1 //valid as AutoID is primary key
 1          2           3 // invalid as AutoID is prinary key
```

hope this presentation help you to understand difference

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, actually what I would like to find out more is the pros and cons and should I be using one over the other.

Comment: Isn't the unique id in the second case in the OP's question a [**Surrogate Key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). It will be better if you add this to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the differences and implications of creating a composite key and a unique id for e.g.

You'll need to create a "natural" key on {CountryID, LanguageID} to avoid duplicated connections **in any case**. The only question is whether you'll **also** need a "surrogate" key on {AutoID}?

Reasons for a surrogate key:

- There are child tables that reference this junction table (and you'd like to keep their FKs slim or prevent ON CASCADE UPDATE propagation).
- You are using an ORM that likes simple PKs.

Unless some of these reasons apply, use only the natural key.

*BTW, under a DBMS that supports [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), a natural key like this is usually a good candidate for a clustering key. If you cluster the table, every other index (such as the one underneath the surrogate key) has extra overhead (compared to an index in  a heap-based table) since it needs to keep the copy of clustering key data and can cause a double-lookup.*

See also: [A column as primary key or two foreign keys as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230062/a-column-as-primary-key-or-two-foreign-keys-as-primary-key/11230592#11230592).